# Move Team Foundation Server Collection TFS 2015 to 2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to move a collection from an old server to a new, there are other collections that are going to stay on the old server in the same domain.

I followed the process of 
Old server: TFS 2015 SQL 2012
Backup database
Detach collection 
Backup database

New Server: TFS 2017 SQL 2016
Restore database
Attach collection

This all went by without an issue, the log shows that the collection was upgraded and if I connect via visual studio it all works.  The issue is when I navigate to the URL the page loads and says the widget failed to load and there are no navigation options on the page.

why is the site broken ?

Comment: You are going to have to be way more specific....

Comment: If you connect to me in SkypeForBusiness at martin@nkdagility.com I will be able to take a look....

Comment: Please share detailed logs, screenshots will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Your TFS 2015 server may have had an extension installed that is breaking now that you upgraded to TFS 2017. Try uninstalling any extensions, and re-install them if you want to keep them.

[According to Microsoft's documentation on known issues in TFS 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#a-idknownissues-aknown-issues):

> External extensions do not automatically upgrade when upgrading TFS
>
> - Issue:
>
>   If you downloaded an extension from the Visual Studio Marketplace, published it to your TFS 2015 installation, and then upgraded to TFS
>     2017, the extension will not be automatically updated when new
>     versions of the extension are published to the Marketplace.
> - Workaround:
>
>   After upgrading to TFS 2017, uninstall the extensions you had installed in TFS 2015. Then reinstall the latest extensions. In TFS
>     2017 we added a feature to automatically check for updated external
>     extensions once a day and upgrade them.

If the extension was made in-house, then you'll need to re-compile it.

> Custom TFS server plugins need to be rebuilt against TFS 2017 DLLs
>
> - Issue:
>
>   Custom TFS server plugins do not work after upgrading to TFS 2017.
> - Workaround:
>
>   Rebuild your custom server plugins against the TFS 2017 assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I could find nothing in the logs that pointed to any issues, in the end I created another server as the same version as the source and then upgraded that so 2017 then move the collection to the target machine, this solved the issue